# Show, that $c$ and $c_0$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $c=\lbrace x=\lbrace x_n\rbrace ,n\in \mathbb{N}: \exists  \, \text{lim}_{n\to \infty}x_n\rbrace$ and $c_0=\lbrace x=\lbrace x_n\rbrace ,n\in \mathbb{N}: \text{lim}_{n\to \infty}x_n=0\rbrace$. 
I want to show that $c$ anc $c_0$ are Banach (I have to show that both are complete metric spaces).

Is it enough to show that $\text{lim}_{n\to \infty}x_n$ belongs to space?

*These are my thoughts:*

Let: $$x^{(n)}=\left( x^{(n)}_j\right)_{j=1}^\infty =(x^{(n)}_1,x^{(n)}_2,\dots )$$ be a Cauchy sequence in $c$.

Lets define the $\infty$-norm $||\cdot||_\infty$:
$$||(x_j)_{j\geqslant 0}||_\infty = \text{sup}_{j\geqslant 0} |x_k|$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$||x_j^{(n)}-x_k^{(m)}||<\varepsilon,\,\,\,\forall n,m >n_0$$
$$\text{sup}_{j\geqslant 0} |x_j^{(n)}-x_j^{(m)}|<\varepsilon,\,\,\,\forall n,m >n_0$$
$$|x_j^{(n)}-x_j^{(m)}|<\varepsilon,\,\,\,\forall n,m >n_0, \,\,\,\forall j\geqslant 0$$

Now I have to prove that $$\text{lim}_{n\to\infty} x^{(n)}= x$$
and $$x\in c.$$

Unfortunately I don't know how to show that $x\in c$.

Comment: Show that every Cauchy sequence converges in $c_0$. If $x^{(n)}=(x^{(n)}_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $c_0$ then pick a subsequence $(x^{(n_{k,1})})_{k=1}^\infty$ with $|x^{(n_{k,1})}-x_1|<k^{-1}$ for each $k$ and some $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$. Now find a *further* subsequence $(x^{(n_{k,2})})_{k=1}^\infty$ with $|x^{(n_{k,2})}_2-x_2|<k^{-2}$ for some $x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Etc. Set $x=(x_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ so that the diagonal sequence $(x^{(n_{k,k})})_{k=1}^\infty$ satisfies $|x^{(n_{k,k})}_j-x_j|<k^{-1}$ and hence $\|x^{(n_{k,k})}-x\|<k^{-1}$. This is the idea for $c_0$, and $c$ is similar.

Comment: Although, it might be easier (and more interesting) to prove that $c$ is Banach by simply showing that the map $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)\mapsto(L,x_1-L,x_2-L,x_3-L,\cdots)$ is a linear isomorphism between $c$ and $c_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X. \vert \cdot \vert)$ be some Banach space.
Let $(x^{(n)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq c$ be a Cauchy sequence, where $x^{(n)}=(x_k^{(n)})_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ is a convergent sequence. We define

$$ x_{\infty}^{(n)}:= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k^{(n)}.$$

We need to construct $x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\in c$ such that $x^{(n)} \rightarrow x$ in the supremum norm. As usual we construct a candidate and verify that indeed this is the desired limit.

We prove first that the pointwise limit of each coordinate exists. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$ holds

$$ \Vert x^{(m)} - x^{(n)} \Vert <\epsilon.$$

Fix some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then we get

$$ \vert x_k^{(m)} - x_k^{(n)} \vert \leq \Vert x^{(m)} - x^{(n)} \Vert <\epsilon.$$

Hence, $(x_k^{(l)})_{l\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ forms a Cauchy sequence in $X$. As $X$ is a Banach space there exists $x_k := \lim_{l \rightarrow \infty} x_k^{(l)}$. We found our candidate, namely $x:=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$. We need to check that $x\in c$. For this we note that for $m,n\geq N$ (where $N$ is chosen as above) we get

$$ \vert x_{\infty}^{(m)} - x_{\infty}^{(n)} \vert = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{\vert x_k^{(m)} - x_k^{(n)} \vert}_{< \epsilon, \text{by choice of }N} \leq \epsilon.$$

Hence, $(x_{\infty}^{(l)})_{l\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ forms a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Again, as $X$ is a Banach space, the limit exist and we call it $x_{\infty}:= \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} x_{\infty}^{(l)}$. This is our candidate for the limit of $(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Let $\epsilon >0$, choose $\tilde{N}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\tilde{n}\geq \tilde{N}$ holds $\vert x_{\infty}^{(\tilde{n})} -x_{\infty} \vert <\epsilon/3$. Choose $\tilde{K}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\tilde{k}\geq \tilde{K}$ holds $\vert x_k -x_k^{(\tilde{n})}\vert, \vert x_k^{\tilde{n}} - x_{\infty}^{(\tilde{n})} \vert < \epsilon/3$ (convince yourself, that can we choose such $\tilde{N}, \tilde{K}$). Then holds for every $\tilde{k}\geq \tilde{K}$

$$ \vert x_{\tilde{k}} - x_{\infty} \vert \leq 
\vert x_{\tilde{k}} - x_{\tilde{k}}^{(\tilde{n})} \vert 
+ \vert x_{\tilde{k}}^{(\tilde{n})} - x_{\infty}^{(\tilde{n})} \vert
+ \vert x_{\infty}^{(\tilde{n})} - x_{\infty} \vert < \epsilon.$$

Hence, $\lim_{\tilde{k} \rightarrow \infty} x_{\tilde{k}}=x_{\infty}$ and therefore $x\in c$.

We are left to show, that $x^{(n)}\rightarrow x$ in the supremum norm. Choose again $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$ holds $\Vert x^{(m)} - x^{(n)} \Vert < \epsilon/2$. Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Choose $m_k\geq N$ such that $\vert x_k - x_k^{(m_k)} \vert <\epsilon/2$, then holds for every $n\geq N$

$$ \vert x_k - x_k^{(n)} \vert 
\leq \vert x_k -x_k^{(m_k)} \vert + \vert x_k^{(m_k)} -x_k^{(n)} \vert
\leq \epsilon/2 + \Vert x^{(m_k)} - x^{(n)} \Vert < \epsilon.$$

Hence, for $n\geq N$ holds

$$ \Vert x -x^{(n)} \Vert 
= \sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \underbrace{\vert x_k - x_k^{(n)}}_{<\epsilon} \vert <\epsilon.$$

This shows that $(c, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ forms a Banach space. Redoing precisely the same argument would give you that $(c_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ forms a Banach space as well. However, there is an easier way. All we need to show is that $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $c$. This can be shown in the following way:

We define

$$ L: c \rightarrow X, \ L\left((x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \right):= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k.$$

This is a linear functional. In fact it is bounded. Let $x=(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\in c$, then

$$ \vert L(x) \vert = \vert \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k \vert
= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{\vert x_k \vert}_{\leq \sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \vert x_k \vert = \Vert x \Vert} \leq \Vert x \Vert.$$

This mean, $c_0 = L^{-1}(\{ 0\})$ (i.e. the kernel of a continuous linear functional) and therefore $c_0$ is closed subspace of a Banach space and hence a Banach space itself.

Comment: That helped me alot. I would like to thank you for proof.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my mind around $\vert x_{\tilde{k}} - x_{\tilde{k}}^{(\tilde{n})} \vert$ - how does it work? Isn't $x_{\tilde{k}}$ a sequence of sequences and $x_{\tilde{k}}^{(\tilde{n})}$ a n-th sequence in $x_{\tilde{k}}$? How can we take a modulus of it!?

Comment: Not quite, $x=(x_k)$ where $$x_k =\lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} x_k^{(l)}$$ this is the limit of the original sequence where we consider just the $k$th entry of that sequence.

Comment: @НикитаВасильев What is it that we want to show? We want to show, that if we have a sequence of sequences (that is $(x^{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$) such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x_k^{(n)}$ exists (which is exactly that $(x^{(n)}_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\in c$) which is Cauchy in the $c$. Now we want to this sequence actually converges. How do we usually do this? Well, we first construct some candidate and then check this is indeed the limit of the sequence.

Comment: You should think of this as functions $f_n: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which we want to converge uniformly to some limiting function $f$. What we usually do, is to show that the pointwise limit exists and then use this as a candidate for the uniform limit. This is exactly what I am doing in the proof above. I fix the $k$th entry (which as functions would correspond to consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(k)$). I hope this helps you more, than it confuses you.